# Как сделать активный центральный слайд в Owl Carousel 2 большего размера, чем остальные

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, owl-carousel

На сайте есть некоторая Owl Carousel 2.

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div><img src="images/full_pic_1.png" alt="picture"/></div>
     <div><img src="images/full_pic_2.png" alt="picture"/></div>
     <div><img src="images/full_pic_3.png" alt="picture"/></div>
     <div><img src="images/full_pic_4.png" alt="picture"/></div>
     <div><img src="images/full_pic_5.png" alt="picture"/></div>
     <div><img src="images/full_pic_6.png" alt="picture"/></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // Owl Carousel
      let owl = $(".owl-carousel");
      owl.owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        items: 3,
        slideBy: 1,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["",""],
        loop: true,
        stagePadding: 80,
        pullDrag: true,
        margin: 300,
        autoWidth: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        responsive:{
            600:{
                items:1
            }
        }
    });
  })
```

В данном случае конечный результат выглядят как-то так:

[image: Слайды]

Необходимо же добиться вот такого эффекта:

[image: Слайды]

Слайд, который расположен по центру - всегда большего размера, те что по бокам - всегда меньшего. Боковые слайды так и должный частично уходить за пределы блока.

Answer (score 0):

Сам решил вопрос, поработав с CSS.

Owl Carousel 2 автоматически присваивает классы слайдам owl-item, тому что в центре, соответственно, center. Стилизовал их как мне нужно и получил эффект, как на второй картинке.

```
.owl-item img{
 margin-top: 15rem;
 width: auto;
 height: 30rem;
}

 .center img{
 margin-top: 0;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
```